# If f is a function. How do I find the image of f? What is an 'image'? Please help.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $f$ is a function. How do I find the image of $f$?

$f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ with

$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             3x &   \text{if}  & x \geq 0, \\
             \\ x^4 &  \text{if} & x<0
             \end{array}
   \right.$

I have plotted both $y=3x$ and $y=x^4$ on a graph and found that $f$ is neither injective nor subjective.
I dont really understand what the question means by find the IMAGE of $f$. What does 'find the image' even mean?

Comment: A function is a mapping from one set $A$ to another set $B$.  The image is the set of all points in $B$ that have been mapped.  The image of $f$ is $f(A) = \{f(a)|a\in A\} \subset B$.

Comment: This doesn't seem right.  The input of $f$ is a real number.  Not an ordered pair.  ANd the output is a real and not an ordered pair.  So $f$ is *NOT* a map from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$.  $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: Another name for the image is the range

Comment: "and found that f is neither injective nor **subjective**"  That's important on figuring out the image!  If it were subjective the every real would be mapped to and the *image* would be the set of all real numbers.  But some numbers are *not* mapped to and the are not in the image.  The *image* is the set of all the numbers that *are* mapped to.  That is what the *image* is.

Comment: ...and of course "su(b)jective" should be written "su(r)jective" ("r" instead of "b").

Answer (score 2):

The image of a function is the set of all the points in the codomain that are actually values of $f(x)$ for some $x$ in the domain. So a function is surjective just when its image is the whole codomain.

Answer (score 0):

A function is a mapping from one set $A$ to another set $B$.  The image is the set of all points in $B$ that have been mapped.  The image of $f$ is $f(A) = \{f(a)|a\in A\} \subset B$.

In this case $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (you have that wrong in your question).

And the image of $f$ is $f(\mathbb R) = \{f(x)|x \in \mathbb R\}$.

$= \{3x$ if $x \ge 0$ or $x^4$ if $x < 0\}$

> $= \{3x|x \ge 0\} \cup \{x^4|x < 0\}$

.

> $= \{w|\frac 13w \ge 0\} \cup \{w|-\sqrt[4]{w} < 0\}$

.

> $= \{w|w\ge 0\}\cup \{w|w>0\}$

.

.

> $[0, \infty) \cup (0, \infty)$

.

> $[0,\infty) = \mathbb R^+\cup\{0\}$

Comment: thank you so much @fleablood !! I understand this alot better now and sorry about typing my question out wrong. Ive been doing alot of maths for the past 2 weeks. My brain is a little bit fried!!

Comment: I think that what is asked is a simpler description of the image of $f$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe the image more simply than "the set of points that have been mapped".

Answer (score 0):

> "What is an image ?"

The image of a function described by a cartesian equation $y=f(x)$ can be explained as being the shadow of the curve one obtains with the sun placed very far on the right at $(s,0)$ with $s \to \infty$ and a screen placed very far on the left ; here is an example for the function defined by $f(x)=\sin(x)+\sin(5x)$ whose image/range/shadow is the closed interval $[-1,3]$ (in black) : we have placed this shadow on the ordinates axis.

Caution: "shadow" isn't an official name for image set...

[image]